# Fail in JSON using Twig

Tags: templating, entry, json

Inside a JSON template I find an entry using `id`, the result title can't be seen using `entry.title` but I can see it with `entry[0].title`. There is another step or encoding I have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using something like this to get your entry:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(1).id('21') %}
```

then Craft is actually returning an ElementCriteriaModel object, even if it is only one entry.

To ensure that the `entry` variable only contains a single entry, you need to call the `first()` method like this:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(1).id('21').first() %}
```

More details in the docs here: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel